# client server code with a segmentation Fault error

Tags: c, unix

I'm working on a network programming project to write a client server Rock Paper Scissors code. I finished the code and it was working well during the tests before I add this line to the code.

```
findWinner(gameType,pcChoice);
```

when I added the line to the code the code started giving me an error about segmentation fault   from the server side. this is the place that I added the line.

```
while(1)
{
    int gameType;
    printf("Paper, Scissors, Rock game start.\n");

    rc = read(client_sockfd, &gameType, 1);       
srand(time(NULL));
pcChoice = (rand() % 3)+1;
findWinner(gameType,pcChoice);
    gameType  = pcChoice;
    write(client_sockfd, &gameType, 1);

}
```

I am an amature in C and dont know what to do.

```
int pcChoice;
```

it is an integer to keep a random integer from 1 to 3 (rock paper or scissors)

findwinner():

```
void findWinner(int player,int pc)
{
const char *items[3]={"Paper","Scissors","Rock"};
printf("Client: %s\n",items[player-1]);
printf ("Computer: %s\n",items[pc-1]);

switch (player)
{
    case 1:
        switch (pc)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("it is a DRAW\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Computer Wins\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Computer Loses\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR\n");
                exit(0);
        };
        break;
    case 2:
        switch (pc)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Computer Loses\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("it is a DRAW\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Computer Wins\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR\n");
                exit(0);
        };
        break;
    case 3:
        switch (pc)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Computer Wins\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Computer Loses\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("it is a draw\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("ERROR\n");
                exit(0);
        };
        break;
    default:
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Now might be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Pls provide the findWinner function code and also the type and usage info of pcChoice.

Comment: You read/write only one byte of `gameType`. You should use `sizeof gameType` to get the proper size.

Comment: You capture, but don't validate, the return value from `read()`.  You don't check that `gameType` is in the range 1..3 before using it to index into your array of items.  It is likely out of control and causing the crash.

Comment: You also should not set the random seed each time in the loop. Think about what will happen if it's looping several times each second? Then you will set the same seed multiple times and get the same random number each time. Only call `srand` _once_.

Comment: gameType is an integer from 1 to 3 which is sent from the client. Do I need to use `sizeof gameType` instead of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1)
{
    int gameType;
    printf("Paper, Scissors, Rock game start.\n");

    rc = read(client_sockfd, &gameType, sizeof(gameType));       
    srand(time(NULL));
    pcChoice = (rand() % 3)+1;
    findWinner(gameType,pcChoice);
    gameType  = pcChoice;
    write(client_sockfd, &gameType, sizeof(gameType));

}
```

other things that might be problematic are:

Try to explicit null terminate the `char*`

```
const char *items[3]={"Paper\0","Scissors\0","Rock\0"};
```

Are you sure player is never negative or bigger than 3?

```
printf("Client: %s\n",items[player-1]);
printf ("Computer: %s\n",items[pc-1]);
```

Comment: yeah. nothing could send out by client except 1 , 2 or 3 ... but it is programming. I can not be sure :D

Comment: put the printfs in comment and change the while(1) to what I put and see what is going on

Comment: Explicit null termination? Why?

Comment: @femchi what was the problem?

Comment: sizeof . I changed 1byte to the sizeof and it is working
thank you